# Definition of direct sum of Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Given a family $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ of Banach spaces, can anyone please provide me with the  definitions of the following concepts

i) $c_0-$ direct sum

ii) $l^{\infty}$ direct sum

iii) algebraic direct sum

What's difference between these three concepts? Can anyone please elaborate with an example taking a particular family of Banach spaces $\{B(H_i)\}_{i \in I}$ where $H_i$'s are Hilbert spaces of finite dimension, say, $n_i$?

Comment: Source where the names (i) and (ii) are used?

Comment: http://bcc.impan.pl/15TQG/uploads/pdf/discrete.pdf page number 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears be that (i) requires a *sequence* of spaces $(E_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$:

(i) $c_0$ direct sum:
$$\{(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\in\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}E_n :\lim_{n\to\infty}\|x_n\| = 0\}.$$

(ii) $l^\infty$ direct sum:
$$\{(x_i)_{i\in I}\in\prod_{i\in I}E_i :\sup_{i\in I}\|x_i\|<\infty\}.$$

(iii) Algebraic direct sum:
$$\{(x_i)_{i\in I}\in\prod_{i\in I}E_i : x_i\ne 0\hbox{ for only a finite number of indices $i$}\}.$$

Source for (i) and (ii) : [Measure Theory and Functional Analysis](https://books.google.es/books?id=wik8DQAAQBAJ&pg=PA88&lpg=PA88&dq=%22c0-direct%20sum%22&source=bl&ots=PW6YLHOLjr&sig=gUiiu-kev_0dNirDrprtC5_s1As&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ-azZ-pPZAhUGtxQKHbbrC58Q6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=%22c0-direct%20sum%22&f=false)

Comment: Thanx a lot Martin.

Comment: can you provide me with a link where i can download the pdf of the book you have mentioned?

Comment: @Dastan, if the book isn't complete at Google Books, I do not think it's accessible anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

For general (non-sequnce) case of (i) we want the set of all
$(x_i)_{i\in\Bbb I}\in\prod_{i\in I}E_i$ such that for all $\epsilon >0$, the set $\{i \in I : \|x_i\| > \epsilon\}$ is finite.

Comment: Thank you very much for more subtle answer.

Comment: I see this as a necessary condition, but is it sufficient for convergence ? For example a countable collection $(E_i)$ with $||x_i|| = 1/ i$.

Comment: Correct.  This version of (i) is the condition for the $c_0$ direct sum.  Your seqeunce with $\|x_i\|= 1/i$ does belong to it.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't previously know what $c_0$ was. I'm actually looking for info on general uncountable Banach products - do you have any references for such ?